# Pre intense soccer game preparation strategies

Tags: diet, workout-routines, soccer

I have an intense soccer game coming on this Sunday, it's now Monday in my time and I have around 6 days to prepare for the game. A couple of things about my current situation which I need your advice on how to best get my body ready:

1. I do jog and the last time I jog was 4 days ago.
2. My last soccer game was 3 weeks ago. That means I'm not in the best condition for the game unless I start some simple training for myself now.
3. There's no game + training from now until that day (Sunday).
4. I'm generally fit.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to best use this 5-6 days period to improve my chance of having a good performance. What would you advice me to do? Which strategies should I use? Any good diet advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd get better answers from folks who play soccer since there's a whole skills-side that a lot of general fitness people won't be tuned into. Maybe sports.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest maintaining a healthy diet and doing some plyometrics in addition to your running. When I began to do plyometrics before competing in track meets, I started to see pretty significant results considering the short amount of time needed for plyometrics. It's also a great way to stretch before physical activity so you're less injury prone. I don't play soccer, but from the little I've watched, I can tell there's quite a bit of running involved. It definitely helps with sprinting, so I would check it out. Here's more info specifically relating to soccer.

http://www.sport-fitness-advisor.com/plyometrics-for-soccer.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dig the plyometrics, but there's evidence showing that stretching pre exercise doesn't reduce injury and can in fact increase them.